# How to add text into Solid Border Bottom?

Tags: css

I've been put in charge of redesigning our communities Sponsor page, Currently this is what it looks like, http://core2062.com/sponsors/ and now I've redesigned it using Flexboxes: [https://diedrich.co/img/uploads/de9ea0e2569a8051f8703c99d637f85b.jpg](http://i.diedrich.co/ewponsorage)

My question is...How do I Put text in the bottom border I created around each image?

Comment: You can't put text in a border. Use a background color on the element holding the text and apply a border(if required) to that. We'd need to see the HTML & CSS of the new page. A short text case in JSFiddle would be ideal.

Comment: You need to provide the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put text in a border. Use a background color on the element holding the text and apply a border(if required) to that

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/U7U6V/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="border">
    <h1>Diamond Sponsors</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.border {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    border-top:5px solid orange;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put text in a border.

You can either make an element with a background color and put the text in that or absolute position the text on top of the border.